# STM32F1 CANbus - receive not working

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus

I am dealing with a CAN RX problem. I am using STM32F103C8T6 and CubeMX code generator. Transmitting is OK without a problem but I am not able to receive any message, if I using polling MCU every time goes into HardFault and if I use interrupt mode it does nothing. My goal is to receive message and send some message like confirmation of receive. Here is the code:

```
   /**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Description        : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2017 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"

CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  CanTxMsgTypeDef msg;

  msg.StdId = 0x666;
  msg.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
  msg.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  msg.DLC = 2;
  msg.Data[0] = 0xAA;
  msg.Data[1] = 0xAA;
  hcan.pTxMsg = &msg;

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(&hcan,CAN_FILTER_FIFO0);

      msg.IDE = hcan.pRxMsg->IDE;
      msg.DLC = hcan.pRxMsg->DLC;
      msg.Data[0] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[0];
      msg.Data[1] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[1];
      msg.Data[2] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[2];
      msg.Data[3] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[3];
      msg.Data[4] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[4];
      msg.Data[5] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[5];
      msg.Data[6] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[6];
      msg.Data[7] = hcan.pRxMsg->Data[7];
      msg.StdId = hcan.pRxMsg->StdId;
      msg.RTR = hcan.pRxMsg->RTR;

      HAL_CAN_Transmit(&hcan, 10);
  }
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* CAN init function */
static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{

    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef  sFilterConfig;

  hcan.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 2;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_5TQ;
  hcan.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.NART = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

   sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
   sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
   sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
   sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
   sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 0;

   if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Filter configuration Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }

   HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_RX1_IRQn,0,0);
     HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_RX1_IRQn);

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();

      /**CAN GPIO Configuration
      PA11     ------> CAN_RX
      PA12     ------> CAN_TX
      */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

EDIT:

Now i am able to use interrupts, but still i have problem - from interrupt handle there is the call to HAL_CAN_Receive_IT() and here it jumps to Hard fault from this line:

```
  if (hcan->pRxMsg->IDE == CAN_ID_STD)
```

EDIT2:

Here is the HAL_CAN_Receive_IT() function:

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef CAN_Receive_IT(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan, uint8_t FIFONumber)
{
  /* Get the Id */
  hcan->pRxMsg->IDE = (uint8_t)0x04 & hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RIR;
  if (hcan->pRxMsg->IDE == CAN_ID_STD)
  {
    hcan->pRxMsg->StdId = (uint32_t)0x000007FF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RIR >> 21);
  }
  else
  {
    hcan->pRxMsg->ExtId = (uint32_t)0x1FFFFFFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RIR >> 3);
  }

  hcan->pRxMsg->RTR = (uint8_t)0x02 & hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RIR;
  /* Get the DLC */
  hcan->pRxMsg->DLC = (uint8_t)0x0F & hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDTR;
  /* Get the FMI */
  hcan->pRxMsg->FMI = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDTR >> 8);
  /* Get the data field */
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[0] = (uint8_t)0xFF & hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDLR;
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[1] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDLR >> 8);
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[2] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDLR >> 16);
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[3] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDLR >> 24);
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[4] = (uint8_t)0xFF & hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDHR;
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[5] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDHR >> 8);
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[6] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDHR >> 16);
  hcan->pRxMsg->Data[7] = (uint8_t)0xFF & (hcan->Instance->sFIFOMailBox[FIFONumber].RDHR >> 24);
  /* Release the FIFO */
  /* Release FIFO0 */
  if (FIFONumber == CAN_FIFO0)
  {
    __HAL_CAN_FIFO_RELEASE(hcan, CAN_FIFO0);

    /* Disable FIFO 0 message pending Interrupt */
    __HAL_CAN_DISABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP0);
  }
  /* Release FIFO1 */
  else /* FIFONumber == CAN_FIFO1 */
  {
    __HAL_CAN_FIFO_RELEASE(hcan, CAN_FIFO1);

    /* Disable FIFO 1 message pending Interrupt */
    __HAL_CAN_DISABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP1);
  }

  if(hcan->State == HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_RX)
  {
    /* Disable interrupts: */
    /*  - Disable Error warning Interrupt */
    /*  - Disable Error passive Interrupt */
    /*  - Disable Bus-off Interrupt */
    /*  - Disable Last error code Interrupt */
    /*  - Disable Error Interrupt */
    __HAL_CAN_DISABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_EWG |
                               CAN_IT_EPV |
                               CAN_IT_BOF |
                               CAN_IT_LEC |
                               CAN_IT_ERR  );
  }

  if(hcan->State == HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX_RX) 
  {
    /* Disable CAN state */
    hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Change CAN state */
    hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_READY;
  }

  /* Receive complete callback */ 
  HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(hcan);

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

Comment: If you get a hard fault for simply trying to receive data, then it would seem that the problem is located elsewhere. Perhaps there is no ISR properly setup to handle the data.

Comment: Well, when you step through the polling rx with your JTAG debugger, which line does it fail on?  If you have no source-level hardware debugger, you're essentially stuft.

Comment: I dunno exact line now but basically it happens when i transmit can message from pc, so it may be some problem with interrupt....

Comment: IME, it's more likely to be the acceptance filter - you should make sure it's completely disabled for initial testing.  If you are using rx interrupts, you really, really need a debugger - put a breakpoint on the first line of the handler, send some data and see if it fires.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit  i putted brakpoint into the handler and it jumps do hardfault from this line 

if (hcan->pRxMsg->IDE == CAN_ID_STD)

Comment: The function HAL_CAN_Receive_IT() is not included in your question.

Comment: I just realised mcu is using interrupt CAN1_RX0 instead of CAN1_RX1 that is why interrupt library from CubeMX not working, if  I "implement" it by myslef it si at least go to interrupt rutine trough CAN1_RX0 interrupt but still i am ending in interrupt HardFault. Polling still not working. I am desperate now :/ Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have a hardfault because `hcan->pRxMsg` is a NULL pointer. You should assign a valid pointer here:

```
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  CanTxMsgTypeDef msg;
  CanRxMsgTypeDef rxMem;

  msg.StdId = 0x666;
  msg.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
  msg.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  msg.DLC = 2;
  msg.Data[0] = 0xAA;
  msg.Data[1] = 0xAA;
  hcan.pTxMsg = &msg;
  hcan.pRxMsg = &rxMem;
```